# Descobrir qual encode foi utilizado em um form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, codificação-de-caracteres, web-crawler, encode

Estou fazendo uma request para o site: http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?PAS

Antes de fazer a request, eles fazem um encode dos filtros.
Por exemplo, quando eu passo

> Práticas não-equitativas

ele encoda para

> Pr%E1ticas+n%E3o-equitativas

O meu problema é conseguir fazer o mesmo encode que o site faz.

Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o encode utilizado, e se tem com descobrir?

Answer (score 3):

O encode parece ser ISO-8859-1, porque está usando apenas um caractere por letr acentuada. Se fosse UTF-8 usaria duas ou mais.

A propósito, essa transformação de "á" para %E1, entre outras, não é encoding, é apenas conversão para o formato URL, que aceita apenas um subconjunto do ASCII.